# Link which leads to comments

Tags: 7, theming

I simply wish to put a link at the head of node, which leads at the beginning of comments.

I did not find clear answer on this subject.

I try this, but does not work :

```
<?php print l('<p>title</p>', '#comments', array('html' => TRUE)); ?>
```

Is there a solution under drupal?

Answer (score 0):

Creating a link like this will not create the desired output. When looking at the `l()` function [comments on the Drupal API page](https://api.drupal.org/comment/24083#comment-24083), the following is suggested to make internal anchors work:

```
l(t('Comments'), $_GET['q'], array('fragment' => 'comments'));
```

What happens is you tell Drupal to create a link to the current page, and add `#comments` as an anchor (fragment).

This means you can also link to the comments from other pages, by simply changing the `$_GET['q']` parameter to the desired path.